# Python - flatten irregular list

Tags: python, list

how do I flatten this list:

```
irr_list = [[[u'Animal Collective'], u'Lion in a Coma'], [[u'Animal Collective'], u'Hocus Pocus'], [[u'Animal Collective'], u'Vertical'], [[u'Animal Collective'], u'Natural Selection'], [[u'Animal Collective'], u'Spilling Guts'], [[u'Animal Collective'], u'Recycling']]
```

for this desired output?

```
output = [[u'Animal Collective', u'Lion in a Coma'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Hocus Pocus'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Vertical'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Natural Selection'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Spilling Guts'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Recycling']]
```

I have tried :

```
flattened = [val for sublist in irr_list for val in sublist]
```

to no avail

Comment: So is it always `[['Animal Collective'], '...']`? Just do `[[i[0][0], i[1]] for i in irr_list]`

Comment: What have you tried? Check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) wiki.

Comment: please refer to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your list is always of the form `[[list, element], [list, element], ...]` then you could use a list comprehension

```
output = [[l[0], e] for l, e in irr_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools

new_data = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[b] if not isinstance(b, list) else b for b in i])) for i in irr_list]
```

Output:

```
[[u'Animal Collective', u'Lion in a Coma'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Hocus Pocus'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Vertical'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Natural Selection'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Spilling Guts'], [u'Animal Collective', u'Recycling']]
```